# Modelsim: Analog Waveform of grouped signals

Tags: modelsim

I have a std_logic_vector in my design of say (31 downto 0). In fact it is an SPI command word, containing command, address and data.

I'd like to see the actual data of that std_logic_vector in an analog waveform in modelsims waveform viewer.

I just drag the signals (19 downto 4) into the waveform viewer and group them.
Now, I was expecting that I can right click on the group and select 'Format->Analog(automatic)'. But I cannot select this, because it is greyed out.

Is there another way to generate an analog wave form from a sub std_logic_vector?

Regards,
Maik

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the option `Combine Signals` instead of `Group` then you can right-click and select `Format->Analog(automatic)`

Comment: Thanks, that just works! I was looking for something in the context menu of the wave editor. Now I know where to look!

Answer (score 0):

If you use Tcl for your waveform files, you can use a command along the lines of:

```
virtual signal -install /tb_top/block_inst { /tb_top/block_inst/signal_bus(7 downto 0) } combined_abc
add wave -group {Test} -group {Combined Waveforms} -radix unsigned -format Analog-Step -height 40 -max 256 /tb_top/block_inst/combined_abc
```

If you've already got your waveforms, but have to create them manually every time, then do a 'File - Save Format...' and call it wave.do or something similar. Then when you want to recall your waveforms 'File - Load - Macro File...'.

The generated wave.do file can be simplified with use of wildcards, etc.